# How to validate select option using ant design

Tags: reactjs, validation, antd

I created a select option using ant design. Inside the option, three values are hardcoded  and one is Input field functionality work fine but when I created a rule for validations not working (when we select hardcoded options validation work but select Input validation not work).

Here my `onchange` functions for select and Input

```
 handleChange(value) {
    console.log(`selected ${value}`);
     this.setState({
         bank:value,
     });
}

 onChangeBank(event){
    this.setState({
        bank:event.target.value
    });
}
```

Here me select form

```
 <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="Bank" >
              {getFieldDecorator('bank',{ rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please provide bank name!' }]}
              )(
                  <Select
                      showSearch
                      style={{ width: 400 }}
                      placeholder="Select a Bank"
                      optionFilterProp="children"
                      onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}

                  >
                     <option value="Bank1">Bank1</option>
                      <option value=" Bank2"> Bank2</option>
                      <option value=" Bank3"> Bank3</option>
                      <option value={this.state.bank}> <Input style={{border:'none',height:30}} type="text" placeholder="Type here" onChange={this.onChangeBank.bind(this)}/></option>
                  </Select>              )}</FormItem>
```

Comment: tried to use `value.target.value`?

Comment: yes i added but error display like this  'value' is not defined  no-undef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are overriding the default `onChange` event, you need to manually set the fields value on your `onChange` handler.

This should be done in addition to your call to `setState`, as `this.state` will not be read by the form.

In effect, you will want to add (assuming you have form as a prop):

```
this.props.form.setFieldsValue({bank: event.target.value})
```

I hope this helps.